# If $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are roots $x^3+7x^2-8x+3,$ find the polynomial with roots $a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

If $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are the roots of the cubic $x^3+7x^2-8x +3,$ find the cubic polynomial whose roots are:
$a_1^2,a_2^2,a_3^2$ and the polynomial whose roots are $\frac{1}{a_1}, \frac{1}{a_2}, \frac{1}{a_3}.$ Not really sure where to go. Hints appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid this is an exact duplicate of [this older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/708567/11619). I'm not sure that that would be the first incarnation of the idea VERY NICELY described by pre-kidney(+1). either?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: You had a very similar Neat answer before! But we  have to credit pre-kidney with a cool application of Viete.

Comment: Of course we do, @orangeskid! His way of doing it makes it much clearer. I closed this as a dup, because it is the exact same polynomial (probably an exercise in some book). The alternative would be to merge the two questions. I need to think about this more. I don't want to merge this with the older one because then pre-kidney would lose the 15 points for acceptance. May be we end up merging the older with this one even though usually I give the older version the courtesy of road without thinking (as a "punishment" to the lazy asker, who should have searched properly first).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Excellent, thanks for assist! Was gonna add the trick with companion matrices, but holding it for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $x^3+7x^2-8x+3=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$. Using difference of squares,
$$
\begin{align*}
(x^2-a_1^2)(x^2-a_2^2)(x^2-a_3^2)&=\left[(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)\right]\left[(x+a_1)(x+a_2)(x+a_3)\right]\\
&= \left[x^3+7x^2-8x+3\right]\left[x^3-7x^2-8x-3\right]\\
&=x^6-65 x^4+22 x^2-9.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore $(x-a_1^2)(x-a_2^2)(x-a_3^2)=x^3-65x^2+22x-9$.

Comment: Great idea, in the intermediate step you forgot to put $\sqrt{x}$ instead of $x$ -- the square roots of course go away.

Comment: Hence, in general it's $P(\sqrt{x}) \cdot P(- \sqrt{x})$. Cool!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Fixed the square roots.

Comment: No worries. Your method finds fast the polynomial with roots $a_i^n$.

Comment: Yes, the same trick works in general (just take product over roots of unity). It also includes the $1/a_i$ case as the special case $n=-1$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

For the first let $y=x^2$

$\implies x^2(x+7)=8x-3\implies y=x^2=\dfrac{8x-3}{x+7}$

Express $x$ in terms of $y$ and put the value of $x$ in the given cubic equation and simplify.

For the second, let $z=\dfrac1x\implies x=\dfrac1z$

and put the value of $x$ in the given cubic equation  and simplify.

Comment: You also have to make sure you end up with a cubic polynomial (as asked in the op). E.g. substituing $x=\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't leave you with a cubic polynomial, but multiplying both sides by $x^3$ makes it a cubic polynomial and also doesn't change the roots of the expression.

Comment: @user26486, By simplify, I meant $$x=1/z\implies1/z^3+7/z^2-8/z+3=0\iff\dfrac{1+7z-8z^2+3z^3}{z^3}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

For the second,
if
$f(x) 
= x^3+ux^2+vx+w
=0
$
then,
if
$g(x)
=x^3f(1/x)
= x^3(1/x^3+u/x^2+v/x+w)
= 1+ux+vx^2+wx^3
$
$g(x)$
 has the same roots as
$f(1/x)$
as long as none of the roots
are zero.

Therefore,
just reverse the order of the coefficients:

$3x^3-8x^2+7x+1$.